# How to use slanted, bold, sans serif, or typewriter IPA symbols (TIPA) in ClassicThesis?

Tags: fonts, linguistics, classicthesis, tipa

I want to use slanted IPA symbols in ClassicThesis. I am using the TIPA package. According to the package's documentation, the code below should give slanted, bold extended, sans serif, and typewriter versions of IPA symbols.

```
\textipa{f@"nEtIks} \\
Slanted: \textipa{\slshape f@"nEtIks} \\
Bold extended: \textipa{\bfseries f@"nEtIks} \\
Sans serif: \textipa{\sffamily f@"nEtIks} \\
Typewriter Text: \textipa{\ttfamily f@"nEtIks}
```

However, it doesn't seem to work. The commands \slshape and \bfseries don't have any effect, and the commands \sffamily and \ttfamily correctly change the family but they break TIPA (i.e. the phonetic symbols are not substituted for input characters).

[image: \slshape, \bfseries, \sffamily, \ttfamily not working with TIPA in Classic Thesis]

I am compiling with LuaLaTeX in Overleaf. I will be very grateful for help. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. Can you please edit your question to show a small compilable document that shows the problem, not just the code fragment you give. TIPA isn't really designed to be used with LuaTeX. I would recommend using IPA directly in your source with a font that supports them.

Comment: The best option for you might be to switch to Unicode with `fontspec`. The `tipauni` package might help, or you could input the IPA characters in Unicode, with any font that supports them.

Comment: If you want to keep using the `tipa` fonts, you might need to define a `substitutefont` for the 8-bit T3 encoding. The available sans-serif fonts are `phv` or `cmss`, and the available monospace font is `cmtt`.

Comment: It’s difficult to determine exactly what code you would need, however, without a complete [MWE.](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that)

Answer (score 2):

As @Davislor mentions in their comments, you can try package [`tipauni`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tipauni). It loads Charis SIL by default. It has a bold variant, but it is a serif font. Also sorry but I couldn't find a typewriter font with IPA characters.

## Serif + Sans (Charis SIL + DejaVu Sans)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tipauni}
\newfontfamily\dejavu{dejavusans}

\begin{document}
\textipa{f@"nEtIks}

Slanted: {\dejavu\slshape\textipa{f@"nEtIks}}

Bold: {\bfseries\textipa{f@"nEtIks}}

Sans serif: {\dejavu\textipa{f@"nEtIks}}
\end{document}
```

[image: 1]

## Only Sans (DejaVu Sans)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[documentfont=dejavusans]{tipauni}

\begin{document}
\textipa{f@"nEtIks}

Slanted: {\slshape\textipa{f@"nEtIks}}

Bold: {\bfseries\textipa{f@"nEtIks}}
\end{document}
```

[image: 2]